# Coldfusion cffile parameter breaks page

Tags: coldfusion

I'm trying to have a simple camera file upload app to where when I take a picture and it uploads to my web server; as well as renaming the file in the process. I have managed to figure out how to upload the file with `action="upload"`. However, when I create another `cffile action="rename"` and start adding cffile parameters it breaks my page.

I know upload is working cause when I check my server, the file is getting uploaded even though my page is breaking. Also I know i have no validation on this as im just trying to get the functionality working then I'll perform validation.

Here is what I tried:

**HTML**

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="testupload.cfm">
  <input type="file" name="fileUpload" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
  <input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

**ColdFusion:**

```
<cfset newfileName = "test">
<cffile 
  action="upload" 
  accept="image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/png" 
  destination="C:\uploads\" 
  nameconflict="makeunique" 
  filefield="form.fileUpload"
/>
<cffile 
  action="rename" 
  source="C:\uploads\#cffile.serverFileName#" 
  destination="C:\uploads\#newfileName#.#cffile.serverFileExt#"
/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (concatenate strings):

```
<cfset newfileName = "test">
<cffile 
  action="upload" 
  accept="image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/png" 
  destination="C:\uploads\" 
  nameconflict="makeunique" 
  filefield="form.fileUpload"
/>

<cfset sourcePath = "C:\uploads\" & #cffile.serverFileName# & "." & #cffile.serverFileExt# />
<cfset destinationPath = "C:\uploads\" & #newFileName# & "." & #cffile.serverFileExt# />

<cffile 
  action="rename" 
  source="#sourcePath#" 
  destination="#destinationPath#"
/>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. However, when I try to re-upload the Image it just uploads the image to the web server and breaks my page without renaming it to "test.jpg"

Comment: One second I enabled debugging but when I get thrown the error nothing shows up on the page it just redirects me to another page

Comment: `source="C:\uploads\#cffile.serverFileName#"` was missing the dot and the extension

Comment: Okay thank you for the clarification I spent like 2 hours trying to figure out what I did wrong. I'm still a beginner! I'm going to try to re-produce the same problem so I understand it more clearly.

Comment: When you're not sure use `cfdump` to see a variable, like `<cfdump var="#cffile.serverFileName#" />`